# How to generate trusted self signed certificate with SHA2 signing algorithm using keytool?

Tags: ssl, keytool, sha, jetty-8

I am trying to establish a secure connection for my application using jetty http server version 8.1.8.v20121106 with self signed certificate.

I am generating self signed certificate with the following command,

1. keytool -genkey -alias mykey -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -sigalg SHA256withRSA -validity 365 -keypass password -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password
2. keytool -export -alias mykey -file server.cer -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password
3. keytool -import -alias mykey -file server.cer -keystore truststore.jks -storepass password

So, totally 3 files generate (keystore.jks,server.cer,truststore.jks)

After the server gets started, I got the following error in my browser. **There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID).**

[image]

[image]

Could anyone help me to generate a trusted self signed certificate using keytool.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since it is self signed certificate, you have to add the self signed certificate to your browser's trust store (Trusted Certificate Authorities).

You can find more details here -->  https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_SSL

Comment: Even though I have installed the certificate (server.cer) to Trusted Certificate Authorities, unable to access my url with secured connection.

Comment: which version of  java you are using ?

Comment: I am using jdk 1.7.0 b147

Comment: Thanks @ObuliSundar... I tried with jdk 1.7.0._79 ... its working fine :-)

Comment: SHA2 has exactly nothing to do with it. You aren't using it, and nobody mentioned it in an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the problem with java jdk. I have verified using java 1.8 and jdk1.7.0_79 it is working fyn for me. Change your java jdk version and verify. For further clarification, Please refer this link.
 https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=398644